# How to pass a dataset to a function without passing it as an argument in Python function

Tags: python, class, global-variables

I am writing a function that will be optimized later and therefore I cannot pass the data to this function as argument. my arguments of the function are limited to those that goes to my optimization process.

I need to pass data somewhere in the function and I was wondering how could I do that using Global variable or classes. currently I am reading the "data" within the function which is not right because every time my data gets updated I have to update the function.

If I write the function in my script, it works with no error. but I am writing it as a module that will be imported later into my script.

here is my function:

```
def f (args):

    data = pd.read_csv('/path.to.train.data')

    do something....
    return something
```

Comment: Why cannot you pass the data as a function parameter?

Comment: you could move it outside the function, and pass it in as a variable, just rename it. would also move the function import outside of the function.

Comment: @SergeBallesta because later I will use bayesianoptimization function from bayes_opt package which only gets a function and set of values for parameters and not the data.

Comment: @matman9 this is a module and I call it into my script. if I take it out, when I want to call my function, it throws an error that dtrain is missing.

Comment: bo_xgb_evaluate is a module?

Comment: @matman9 yes it is a module.

Comment: how do you run the function?

Comment: @matman9 I put this function in a utils.py module and I call it as utils.bo_xgb_evaluate. Then I use it in my optimizer optimizer = BayesianOptimization(bo_xgb_evaluate, params)

Comment: is the problem that the name of the dtrain data changes?

Comment: @matman9 no it wont change, I just wanted to be able to pass training data in case the data itself changes before running the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe split your functions up so you would have a function to return `xgbparams` then a function to return `dtrain` and then a function that takes `xgbparams` and `dtrain` to do the calculation.

```
def1():
    return xgbparams

def2():
    return dtrain

def3(xgbparams, dtrain);
    run the thing...
```

Also, by splitting it up you will have a better chance to figure out what works.

Otherwise if you want to create a class you can pass data around by using `self`, `self.dtrain` .

```
class myclass(object):
    import xgboost as xgb
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data)

    etc..
```

and when you initialise the class you just define it as an input and is imported then:

```
myclass('/train.buffer')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But all the parameters in bo_xgb_evaluate will be optimized later and it will throw an error that dtrain is not a parameter to be optimized. That is why I cannot pass it to my function.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a nested function that passes the data to the internal function.

```
def f (args, data):
   "some operations on the data"
   def g(args):
       return something
    other operations 
    return something
```